# Power MOSFET gate driver: voltage and current levels

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

Following are the doubts on the gate driver section of a [forward converter.](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX17598-MAX17599.pdf)

1. Peak drive voltage = 7.4 V (Shouldn't it be higher, say 10 V or so, usually for driving power MOSFETS?)

[image]

2. Peak MOSFET gate sink current = 1.5 A

[image]

Vdrv current limit: 100 mA-> Does that mean, it is the Cvdrv capacitor which provides the high momentary current (1.5 A) while charging the gate of NDRV MOSFET?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> *Peak Drive volatge = 7.4V ( Shouldn't it be higher, say 10V or so,
> usually for driving Power MOSFETS?)*

Check this out just for clarity: -

[image]

The 7.4 volts is enough for many MOSFETs especially logic level devices. Maybe the data sheet mentions the choice of MOSFET. The data sheet does indicate that there is a development board that can be purchased so, follow those links and see what MOSFETs are recommended on it.

> *Vdrv Current limit: 100mA-> Does that mean, it is the Cvdrv capacitor
> which provides the high momentary current (1.5A) while charging the
> gate of NDRV Mosfet?*

This is not the current that can drive the gate of the MOSFET - refer to DRIVER or NDRV for that but, the capacitor mentioned does sustain that NDRV current it seems.

Comment: The EVM board uses  FDS86242 which seems to have negligible difference in Rds (on) at Vgs=  7V and 10V.
Iam still surprised why the manufacturer has gone for 7.4V drive. As @Unimportant commented earlier ( Iam not seeing the comment now!), its the same voltage which would appear at the NDRV pin.

Comment: Yes, the FDS86242 is a very appropriate choice. I do wish Maxim were better at explaining this in their data sheets - they don't help themselves at all these days it seems. Regards the disappeared comment; mine was deleted too - as he was writing his comment I was amending my answer because I realized that NDRV was powered from VDRV (I should have looked at the picture in your question a bit more closely initially). Never mind it's fixed now.